# Trimming in VBScript

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Why would some add the extra & "" in this TRIM command in visual basic?

```
IF Trim(TwitterUserName & "") <> "" THEN
```

What benefit does it offer..?

Many thanks in advance..

Comment: Effectively, it does nothing. I'm curious why the result is compared to 0...weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to `Trim()` a Null etc. will cause a datatype mismatch error. Appending an empty string to the variable forces a conversion to the string datatype and will allow `Trim()` to run without error - though you still need to check if it was truly empty, hence the rest of the code.

It's a bit of a lazy shortcut to preempt errors that has persisted for quite some time - I could not find if it's still even needed in the last version of VBScript.

Answer (score 2):

Voodoo? Joke? Who knows.

Even if TwitterUserName could contain nasty values like Empty or Null, coercing to string and appending an empty string won't help any.

There is a Len() missing to make the comparison against 0 reasonable.